# Generalization of code

Tags: c, rtos, generalization

I'm working on a small Real-Time OS project and I ran into a small problem.

```
void printOutput(void)                                       
{                                                             
   Log_info2("Fib(%d) = %d", FIB_N , cur) ;               
   System_printf("Fib(%d) = %d", FIB_N , cur) ;                   
   System_flush() ;                                                            
}
```

As you can see this function calls both Log and printf functions with the exact same arguments. 
My question is - is there any way to make this piece of code more generalized?

I'd appreciate your ideas.
Thank you

Comment: What does it mean - generalized?

Comment: May or may not be appropriate to have a function that calls both `Log_info2` and `System_printf` (and `System_flush`?)?

Comment: @Ry- That is a function that calls both Log and printf .

Comment: @Jadenkun: I mean one that just forwards its arguments. Or even a macro, if you’re okay with varargs macros.

Comment: @Ry-I don't mind using macros but that doesn't solve the problem of calling both Log and printf with the same arguments, does it?

Comment: Sure it does, unless you consider `Log_info2(format, ...args); System_printf(format, ...args);` where `format` and `args` are inputs to be too repetitive. Not going to get around that.

Comment: @Ry- I guess there's no workaround to this problem then, Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 2):

A small simplification is all you might need.

```
void printOutput(void)                                       
{
   char const* format = "Fib(%d) = %d";
   Log_info2(format, FIB_N , cur);
   System_printf(format, FIB_N , cur) ;
   System_flush();
}
```

Further simplification to reduce code duplicaion.

```
void printOutput(void)
{
   char message[200];  // Make it large enough for your neeeds.
   sprintf(message, "Fib(%d) = %d", FIB_N , cur);

   Log_info2(message);
   System_printf(message) ;
   System_flush();
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to avoid the replication of arguments passed to both functions?

Comment: @Jadenkun, you mean find a way to avoid using `FIB_N` and `cur` two times?

Comment: I thought about this as well. I guess that's the best solution. Thank you

Comment: `#define SUPER_LOG(fmt, ...) LogInfo2(fmt, __VA_ARGS__); System_print(fmt, __VA_ARGS__); System_flush();`